# What is ‘happy satisfaction’?

Tags: meaning

Pleasure: feeling of happy satisfaction and enjoyment.
[enter link description here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pleasure)

Can satisfaction feel happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Happy describes the type of satisfaction felt.

So, in this case, "happy" is an adjective that describes the type of satisfaction - the satisfaction doesn't feel happy, the person feeling the satisfaction would describe it as happy.

This might be contrasted with other forms of satisfaction such as "grim satisfaction", which you might feel while performing revenge on someone who wronged you.